# jarbundler Can't find my jre

Tags: java, info.plist, jarbundler

I want to use Wikipedia API with my java application.

Wikipedia API is using https.

cause I am using OSX, initially I used jre1.6, but https protocol is activated in 1.7.

So I changed my jre version 1.6 to 1.7.

I make jar to app using jarbundler.

I've set jvm version of info.plist 1.7. **but not working.**

It said **"It can't be run without java 1.7"**

my java version :

java version "1.7.0_45"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: Run "which java" from the terminal, then run $PATH_TO_JAVA/java -version ($PATH_TO_JAVA is the output from the previous command). What version do you get?

Comment: my java path /usr/bin/java, i get java version : java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: How'd you change your jre version?

Comment: cd /System/Libarary/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions                 rm CurrentJDK
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/ CurrentJDK     i change java version this way